# reg ex telephone number

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

How do i change any of the following to just numbers

```
1-(999)-999-9999 
1-999-999-9999
1-999-9999999
1(999)-999-9999
1(999)999-9999
```

i want the final product to be 19999999999

Comment: possible duplicate of [A comprehensive regex for phone number validation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/123559/a-comprehensive-regex-for-phone-number-validation)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way would be to strip everything out of your string that's not a number and then see if you end up with a 10 digit number (or 11 if you're making the 1 mandatory):

```
$string = "1-(999)-999-9999";
$number = preg_replace('/[^0-9]/', "", $string); // results in 19999999999
if (strlen($number) == 11)
{
  // Probably have a phone number
}
```

Answer (score 2):

try

```
preg_replace('\D', '', $string);
```

This will filter out any non digits.

Answer (score 0):

You dont really need regex for this...

```
$number = str_replace(array('-', '(', ')'), '', $number);
```

Comment: what about things like `x`, `ext`, `.`, `+`, etc

Comment: If you know the input will be like one of the examples then thats all you need. If you dont know the input then you need more validation anyway.

Answer (score 0):

```
preg_replace('[\D*]', '', '1-(999)-999-9999');
```